# Python scapy prn send rcv error

Tags: python, scapy

I am following this book called violent python and in CH5 it goes over making a script to find the mac address of an iphone wifi side. And check if bluetooth is on by incrementing the last bytes by one. Basically find an iphone that has bluetooth in hidden mode.

I am confused why the script errors out like that. What can I do to prevent this error in the future?

Here is the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scapy.all import *
from bluetooth import *


def retBtAddr(addr):
    btAddr=str(hex(int(addr.replace(':', ''), 16) + 1))[2:]
    btAddr=btAddr[0:2]+":"+btAddr[2:4]+":"+btAddr[4:6]+":"+\
    btAddr[6:8]+":"+btAddr[8:10]+":"+btAddr[10:12]
    return btAddr

def checkBluetooth(btAddr):
    btName = lookup_name(btAddr)
    if btName:
        print '[+] Detected Bluetooth Device: ' + btName
    else:
        print '[-] Failed to Detect Bluetooth Device.'


def wifiPrint(pkt):
    iPhone_OUI = 'd0:23:db'
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        wifiMAC = pkt.getlayer(Dot11).addr2
        if iPhone_OUI == wifiMAC[:8]:
            print '[*] Detected iPhone MAC: ' + wifiMAC
            btAddr = retBtAddr(wifiMAC)
            print '[+] Testing Bluetooth MAC: ' + btAddr
            checkBluetooth(btAddr)


conf.iface = 'wlan1mon'
sniff(prn=wifiPrint)
```

Error message i receive:

```
sudo python 10-iphoneFinder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "10-iphoneFinder.py", line 34, in <module>
    sniff(prn=wifiPrint)
  File "/home/rb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 620, in sniff
    r = prn(p)
  File "10-iphoneFinder.py", line 26, in wifiPrint
    if iPhone_OUI == wifiMAC[:8]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scapy, the `addr2` field in the `Dot11` layer is a conditional field, so it may have a value of `None` when the sniffed packet has no such field.

Here is how we could write the `wifiPrint()` function:

```
IPHONE_OUI = 'd0:23:db:'

def wifiPrint(pkt):
    if Dot11 in pkt:
        wifiMAC = pkt[Dot11].addr2
        if wifiMAC is not None and wifiMAC.startswith(IPHONE_OUI):
            print '[*] Detected iPhone MAC: ' + wifiMAC
            btAddr = retBtAddr(wifiMAC)
            print '[+] Testing Bluetooth MAC: ' + btAddr
            checkBluetooth(btAddr)
```

As a side note, the script is not really well coded, to say the least. Maybe it's not a good idea to learn Scapy (or even Python) from it.